# Unable to SELECT data that is definitely there

Tags: oracle

This is truly strange.  I'm connecting to an Oracle Docker container (epiclabs/docker-oracle-xe-11g) and performing the following operations:

1. `alter database default tablespace users`
2. `create user foo identified by foo`
3. `alter user foo quota unlimited on users`
4. `create table foo.bar`
5. `insert into foo.bar some data` 5 times.
6. Verify that `select count(*) from foo.bar` returns `5`.  So far so good.
7. Open a second connection to the same database.
8. `select * from foo.bar order by baz asc`

*This query returns 0 rows.*

Things I've ruled out:

- The container isn't being reset, because the table `foo.bar` still exists.  (I tried saying `select * from foo.GARBAGE` just to make sure it wasn't erroring out on a missing table and swallowing the error.  It errored as expected.  So the table is there.)
- The second connection isn't a different user with no permissions.  Verified by `select USER from DUAL`.  Same username both times, and if it was a permissions issue I'd expect to see an error.

So... what could be the reason why I'm getting no rows returned from a table I've verified is populated with data, on a query with no WHERE clause?

Comment: Completely normal phenomenon, given that you created a global temporary table.

Comment: @BalazsPapp I did what now?  On any other database, that creates a normal, ordinary table.  What bizarre nonstandard behavior is Oracle up to *this time?*

Comment: @MasonWheeler don't worry, Oracle will only create a global temporary table if you use the obvious syntax `create global temporary table`. I will second the "you probably haven't committed" guess, you mention a driver being configured to auto-commit, what driver you using to connect - are you also using connection pooling? You can check for open transactions with a `sys` connection by querying `v$transaction` and `v$lock`. The other obvious problem is that you are not connecting to the same database - are you running all of the tests from within the container or from your host?

Comment: @AndrewSayer The tests are running from the host.  As I mentioned, I know I have to be connecting to the same database because I've verified that the table exists.  And after I add an explicit `commit` statement, nothing changes.

Comment: @AndrewSayer Just checked.  At the point in question, I've got 0 transactions and 18 locks from 11 distinct SIDs.  Is that expected?

Comment: I suggest you share a full copy and paste of what you're doing and seeing (like what @BalazsPapp has provided as an answer), that will make it easy to spot the mistake. If you are using the same connection string from the same host each time then the only explanation is you are not committing - the lack of transaction rows suggests you are rolling back. Locks without transactions are usually edition locks (type=AE) but you'd only get one of those per SID, either way no transaction means nothing to commit, no rows means they were rolled back (or deleted/truncated by another user process).

Answer (score 2):

Global temporary table was just a guess, because you had not posted the actual statement for table creation, and already said you used explicit commit. Using the information you gave us, we can only guess.

But here it is, works as expected:

```
[root@r5 ~]# docker pull epiclabs/docker-oracle-xe-11g
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from epiclabs/docker-oracle-xe-11g
e92ed755c008: Pull complete
b9fd7cb1ff8f: Pull complete
ee690f2d57a1: Pull complete
53e3366ec435: Pull complete
51f7c9099c0d: Pull complete
1b7f09633195: Pull complete
4a8ff9746209: Pull complete
6bae0d820e30: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:

404173b90d09d0619c854dd469c76c3e7256c88a7aac5d47e05f934ec7afae06
Status: Downloaded newer image for epiclabs/docker-oracle-xe-11g:latest
docker.io/epiclabs/docker-oracle-xe-11g:latest
[root@r5 ~]# mkdir /storage/wdred_3tb_raid/mydata
[root@r5 ~]# docker run -d -v /storage/wdred_3tb_raid/mydata:/u01/app/oracle -p 1521:1521 epiclabs/docker-oracle-xe-11g
29f5bcbd1ccbf88d59111d653830098e6a965c602d07adfad5b331c7be8a4b95
[root@r5 ~]#
```

Test from other machine:

```
[oracle@o81 ~]$ sqlplus system/oracle@\"r5/xe\"

SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Mon May 24 20:31:08 2021
Version 19.11.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-28002: the password will expire within 7 days

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> create user foo identified by foo default tablespace users quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL> grant create table to foo;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> create table foo.bar(c1 number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into foo.bar select rownum from dual connect by level <= 5;

5 rows created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select count(*) from foo.bar;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         5

SQL> connect system/oracle@r5/xe
ERROR:
ORA-28002: the password will expire within 7 days


Connected.
SQL> select count(*) from foo.bar;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         5

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you commit the insert transaction? A second session won't see changes made by the first until the transaction(s) are committed.

```
insert into foo.bar ...;
commit;
```

Comment: No, but the driver should be configured to auto-commit.  Regardless, I added an explicit `commit` at the end of the inserts and re-ran my tests.  The SELECT still returns 0 results.